# Path is not properly set. Cognos will fail to start

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am trying to run Cognos (using IBM Cognos Configuration). But I received this error:

**[ERROR] The variable PATH is not properly set. IBM Cognos will fail to start.**

When I checked my environment variables, it contains:

C:\Program Files\IBM\cognos\c10_64\bin64;

C:\Program Files\IBM\cognos\c10_64\bin;

Did I miss anything? Hoping someone could help me. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following TechNote from IBM about setting the JAVA path (this is normally the problem):
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21340128